# MySQL query is not giving right results

Tags: mysql

My query uses 5 tables which are :

```
categories c- categories_id and its other fields and parent_id field
categories_description cd-  categories_id and categories_name fields.
products_to_categories p2c- products_id linked to categories_id fields

products p- products_id field and other details
specials s- specials_status and products_id
```

I have this MySQL query :

```
SELECT c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id 
FROM categories_description cd, categories c 
LEFT JOIN products_to_categories p2c on p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id 
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
LEFT JOIN specials s ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
and s.specials_status = '1' 
WHERE c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id= 4 
and (c.parent_id = 0 OR c.parent_id = 1059 ) 
GROUP BY c.categories_id 
ORDER by sort_order, cd.categories_name
```

After fetching array this wil give as result:

```
[1059] => Array
    (
        [1109] => Name of 1109
        [1323] => Name of 1323
        [1324] => Name of 1324
        [1322] => Name of 1322
        [1142] => Name of 1142
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [1725] => Name of 1725
        [1077] => Name of 1077
        [95] => Name of 95
        [46] => Name of 46
        [96] => Name of 96
        [1059] => Name of 1059
        [1084] => Name of 1084
        [1386] => Name of 1386
        [1000] => Name of 1000
    )
```

I can not figure out how to exclude categories without active specials (in this case 1322). Replacing LEFT JOIN to JOIN:

```
SELECT c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id 
FROM categories_description cd, categories c 
JOIN products_to_categories p2c on p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id 
JOIN products p ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
JOIN specials s ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
and s.specials_status = '1' 
WHERE c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id= 4 
and (c.parent_id = 0 OR c.parent_id = 1059 ) 
GROUP BY c.categories_id 
ORDER by sort_order, cd.categories_name
```

will give the right results for subcategories but drops my Main categories :

```
[1059] => Array
    (
        [1109] => Name of 1109
        [1323] => Name of 1323
        [1324] => Name of 1324
        [1142] => Name of 1142
    )
```

Tried subquery:

```
SELECT c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id 
FROM categories_description cd, categories c 

JOIN ( select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id FROM categories_description cd, categories c 

JOIN products_to_categories p2c on p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id 
JOIN products p ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
JOIN specials s ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
and s.specials_status = '1' 
WHERE c.categories_id = cd.categories_id  and cd.language_id= 4 and c.parent_id = 1059

 ) derived

WHERE c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id= 4 
and (c.parent_id = 0 OR c.parent_id = 1059 ) 
GROUP BY c.categories_id 
ORDER by sort_order, cd.categories_name
```

gives only main categories:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [1725] => Name of 1725
        [1077] => Name of 1077
        [95] => Name of 95
        [46] => Name of 46
        [96] => Name of 96
        [1059] => Name of 1059
        [1084] => Name of 1084
        [1386] => Name of 1386
        [1000] => Name of 1000
    )
```

Comment: You should explain your schema

Comment: time for a subquery? wrap your logic and in the parent specify a where clause.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea How could I do the subquery?

Comment: @user2834677 this is explained here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html -- there are also quite a few examples.

Comment: @steve thank you for the link. Off course I have read it before and tried diferent approaches but can not get it right.